# Sitecore Backend Labels missing

Tags: sitecore, backend

I have a Sitecore 7.5 instance, where the backend is broken after installing some packages with content, layouts and templates from an old Sitecore 6.3 SIP 3.2 instance and the new built DLLs from the solution. I also merged the config files of both instances.

This is how the backend of the 7.5 instance looks now:

[image]

Any idea what causes this and how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Labels and Save issue fixed. Getting an error message on the website.

Frontend error message:

```
[InvalidOperationException: intranetContext]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsNotNull(Object value, String message) +55
   Sitecore.Intranet.Utils.IntranetUtil.get_CurrentIntranetSite() +403
   Sitecore.Intranet.Settings.IntranetSettings.get_SiteDatabase() +89
   Sitecore.Intranet.Utils.IntranetLanguageResolver.get_LanguageList() +61
   Sitecore.Intranet.Utils.IntranetLanguageResolver.get_FullLanguageList() +188
   Sitecore.Intranet.Utils.IntranetLanguageResolver.GetLanguageList(Boolean isContentArea, Boolean isExclusiveQS) +149
   Sitecore.Intranet.Utils.IntranetLanguageResolver.GetLanguage(Item item, Boolean isContentArea, Boolean isExclusiveQS) +74
   Sitecore.Intranet.Utils.IntranetLanguageResolver.IsContentLanguageAccessible(Item item, Language& language) +135
   Sitecore.Intranet.HtmlControls.LocalizedPlaceholder.EnterContentArea() +81
   Sitecore.Intranet.HtmlControls.LocalizedPlaceholder.OnInit(EventArgs e) +46
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +186
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +291
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +291
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2098
```

Comment: Any chance you're on a different language in the shell?

Comment: What do you mean? How can I check that? Just edited the first post with more information.

Comment: Are there any additional messages in your log files? Seeing as there's more issues it's probably not the language. You can go to a different language by appending this to the URL: ?sc_lang=*language*
So for instance mysite/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?sc_lang=en

Comment: Also check the user account, there are 2 languages, Client Language (set it on "en" or default or de-DE ) and the  Default Content Language this can set on de-DE... and maybe you have set the default client language in your config to something that is not there., set it back to en.

Comment: You right, setting up the client language to de-DE or en fixed the labels, but there is still an error when saving an item. I'm adding the complete error message to the first post.

Comment: Saving fixed by removing the AddNewVersion processor. Now I added an error message that comes up when opening the Frontend / Website.

Comment: Guessing you are using the Sitecore Intranet module? It looks like the [latest version](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20Intranet/Sitecore%20Intranet%204,-d-,1/Release%20Notes/Release%20History.aspx) is not compatible with SItecore 7.5, assuming you upgraded the module as well of course.

Comment: The Intranet module was installed on the old 6.3 instance. On this new 7.5 instance I transferred the used SIP Layouts and the Sitecore.Intranet.dll over and added assembly binding to the web.config.

Comment: Based on the stack trace its trying to find the intranet you are currently viewing but is unable. Are you sure all the necessary items have been added to your new 7.5 instance? Also it could be an issue raised from merging your configs